# 'class' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

What am i doing wrong here. I have been trying to figure this out for hours. I think i am having issues with Django get_context_data function.

Error is **'PatientBedAllotmentList' object has no attribute 'object'**

**views.py**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PatientBedAllotmentList(ListView):
    model = BedAllotment
    template_name = 'room/bed_allotment_list.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PatientBedAllotmentList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    start = BedAllotment.objects.get(id=self.object.id).allotment_date
    end = BedAllotment.objects.get(id=self.object.id).departure_date
    amount = BedCreate.objects.get(id=self.object.id).cost
    days_number = abs((end - start).days)
    days_number = int(days_number)

    amount_due = amount * days_number

    context['account_type'] = AccountUser.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    hospital_id = AccountUser.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id).hospital_id
    allotment_details = BedAllotment.objects.filter(hospital_id=hospital_id)
    context['allotment'] = allotment_details

    context['amount'] = amount_due

    return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from  medisaver.room import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^room-category/create/$', views.RoomCategoryCreate.as_view(), name='room_category_create'),
    url(r'^room-category/list/$', views.RoomCategoryList.as_view(), name='room_category_list'),
    url(r'^room-category/update/(?P<hospital_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.RoomCategoryUpdate.as_view(), name='room_category_update'),
    url(r'^room-category/delete/(?P<hospital_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.RoomCategoryDelete.as_view(), name='room_category_delete'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/list/$', views.RoomList.as_view(), name='room_list'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/create/$', views.RoomCreateView.as_view(), name='room_create'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/update/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<room_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.RoomUpdate.as_view(), name='room_update'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/delete/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<room_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.RoomDelete.as_view(), name='room_delete'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/beds/create/$', views.BedCreateView.as_view(), name='bed_create'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/beds/list/$', views.BedList.as_view(), name='bed_list'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/beds/update/(?P<room_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<bed_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.BedUpdate.as_view(), name='bed_update'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/beds/delete/(?P<room_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<bed_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.BedDelete.as_view(), name='bed_delete'),
    url(r'^hospital-rooms/beds/patient-bed-allotment/$', views.BedAllotmentCreate.as_view(), name='bed_allotment'),
    url(r'^hospital/discharge-patient/(?P<allotment_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.BedDischarge.as_view(), name='patient_bed_discharge'),
    url(r'^hospital/bed-allotment-list/$', views.PatientBedAllotmentList.as_view(), name='patient_bed_list'),
]
```

Comment: What is `self.object` supposed to be? Since this is a `ListView`, it works with *multiple* objects, not one.

Comment: Can you show your  urls

Comment: `self.object` is suppose to link each list to its own object. 
What I'm trying to achieve here is ... A list of rooms assigned to list of patients and showing each amount due for object room and patient

Comment: @SamiulSk edited to show urls

Comment: what is self.object.id?  self.object does not make any sense in ListView. Basically you get all object of your Model here. Hardly you can filter it in get_queryset method. ListView is nothing but Model.objects.all()

Comment: @SamiulSk... Can you guide me on how to achieve that. My brain seems to be on s shut down this moment .. I keep having petty errors.. 

thanks

Comment: Sure, but nobody can say with out knowing what you want in ListView and without watching the models. I think now you know the error is happening because of self.object and that can't be solved in this way, you should come with more specific problem or desctiption

Comment: Thanks, atleast the error has been isolated .. I will figure it out eventually. Thanks

Comment: I think I am getting your point. You want to show the bill to every patient in list view right? That's why you wanted to calculate it?

Comment: Thanks @SamiulSk ... You understood what i wanted to do. I eventually got a fix. Might be longer but it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by calling on `form_valid` function. I used the function on my `BedDischarge` class in my views. And was able to use `self.object`. Then made a template call in my templates.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BedDischarge(UpdateView):
    model = BedAllotment
    template_name = 'room/bed_discharge.html'
    form_class = BedAllotmentUpdateForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'allotment_id'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patient_bed_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BedDischarge, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['account_type'] = AccountUser.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):

        get_allot_id = self.object.id

        bed_allot = BedAllotment.objects.get(id=get_allot_id)

        start_time = bed_allot.allotment_date
        end_time = form.instance.departure_date

        cost = BedCreate.objects.get(id=self.object.bed_id).cost

        days_spent = (end_time - start_time).days
        amount = cost * days_spent

        form.instance.days = days_spent
        form.instance.amount = amount

        return super(BedDischarge, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

self.object does not make any sense in ListView. 
If you want to get stay_time then you can do it in your model and access in template using `object.stay_time` and even you can calculate the amount in template by multiplying. But I You can even do it in detailview. Create a method in that model like

```
@property
def stay_time(self):
    return (self.departure_date-self.allotment_date)
```